# Stream tweets which mention @friendname

Tags: c#, twitter, friend, twitter-follow, tweetinvi

I have a C# application that streams all tweets created by any of my friends successfully (using Tweetinvi library and following code).

```
var userStream = Tweetinvi.Stream.CreateUserStream();

userStream.TweetCreatedByFriend += (sender, args) =>
{
    ConsoleLog(args.Tweet.Text);
}
```

How (if possible) can I listen to the tweets which mention any of my friends' screen name ?
e.g. I am friend with **@alice**. Now **@bob**, who is **NOT** my friend, tweets like this:

```
Hi @alice, how are you ?
```

How can I listen to above tweet by **@bob**, who is **NOT** my friend, and **MAY** or **MAY NOT** be *friend* or *follower* of **@alice**?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Or at least I don't think you can if you have too many friends.
The only solution you currently I currently can see is to use the FilteredStream because it is a public stream and you can access tweets from users that your are not following.

If the list of followers you have is low enough you can do the following

```
var fs = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
fs.AddTrack("@userScreenName");
```

As a result you'll be able to follow all the tweets containing @userScreenName from any user of Twitter.

Comment: Yes, that's seems the only way so far. But because I have to add tracks in an already running stream so stopping/adding track/resuming stream is not likely a reliable solution as I am trying with Tweetinivi. So please let me know if you have better suggestion for this ?

Comment: I will try to have a look into it. But in any case with Tweetinvi or any other API you need to request the endpoint with your parameters. So there is no way to modify a stream while it is already running. You will always have to stop the StreamReader and then restart a StreamReader with the correct endpoint.

Comment: So I am not getting you wrong, Tweetinvi.Stream.TrackedStream.StartStream(endpoint_url_with_parameters) is my case. Where I have to provide updated endpoint url every time new track to be added? Okey, can you please give me a correct example of that endpoint_url following a user @username ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but try using a UserStream and filtering out the UserMentions. I'm right now trying to find a better way of doing this myself. Everytime a user mentions you, they are added to your UserStream.

```
var stream = Tweetinvi.Stream.CreateTweetStream();
stream.TweetReceived += (sender, args) =>
{
         if(args.Tweet.IsRetweet || !args.Tweet.UserMentions.Any((x)=> x.Id == user.Id))
          {
               return;
          }
       //Code to respond to mention here
}
```